# Cannot find and load fbtft module, even if it was enabled in .config

Tags: linux-kernel, framebuffer, buildroot

I've been trying to enable `fbtft` module on a minimal buildroot image for an Orangepi zero board. I've enabled it under `Device Drivers > Graphics Support > Frame Buffer Devices >`  using `make linux-menuconfig`.

```
<M> Support for frame buffer devices  --->
<M> Support for small TFT LCD display modules  --->
```

and under latter, i've enabled `<m> FB driver for the ILI9340 LCD Controller` too.

.config file contains following:

```
...
# BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_EXT_EV3DEV_LINUX_DRIVERS is not set
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_EXT_FBTFT=y
# BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_EXT_AUFS is not set
...
...
# BR2_PACKAGE_FAN_CTRL is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_FBTFT=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_FCONFIG is not set
...
```

Patching of kernel appears during build process:

```
if [ -e /some_path/dev/buildroot/buildroot-2023.02.1/output/build/linux-5.15.16/drivers/video/fbdev ]; then dest=drivers/video/fbdev ; else dest=drivers/video ; fi ; mkdir -p /some_path/dev/buildroot/buildroot-2023.02.1/output/build/linux-5.15.16/${dest}/fbtft; cp -dpfr /some_path/dev/buildroot/buildroot-2023.02.1/output/build/fbtft-274035404701245e7491c0c6471c5b72ade4d491/* /some_path/dev/buildroot/buildroot-2023.02.1/output/build/linux-5.15.16/${dest}/fbtft/ ; echo "source \"${dest}/fbtft/Kconfig\"" >> /some_path/dev/buildroot/buildroot-2023.02.1/output/build/linux-5.15.16/${dest}/Kconfig ; echo 'obj-y += fbtft/' >> /some_path/dev/buildroot/buildroot-2023.02.1/output/build/linux-5.15.16/${dest}/Makefile
```

After building, when I check using `make linux-menuconfig`, above options (Support for etc.) are blank again, and image does not contain anything related to `fbtft`. No kernel messages whatsoever.

Output of `# find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name '*.ko*'`:

```
/lib/modules/5.15.16/extra/xradio_wlan.ko
```

(I've tried clean build too)
What am I missing here?

Comment: "*After building, when I check using make linux-menuconfig ...*" -- Sounds like the default kernel config supplanted your previous mods. You have two choices: (A) perform your kernel config changes *after* an initial build, and then 'make' again. Or (B) save your kernel config changes as a new **defconfig** file (https://superuser.com/questions/439511/how-to-save-or-export-a-custom-linux-kernel-configuration). Save it outside the **output/** directory, such as in the **board/orangepi/** directory, and then reconfig BR to use that file as the kernel's defconfig.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that fbtft isn't available from kernel 5.4 on.
This is what is stated on the FrameBufferTFT git page:

```
fbtft_device and flexfb are gone in 5.4
```

fbtft_device was removed because the gpio code had been reworked without fixing up fbtft_device so it didn't work. fbtft_device was never intended to be included in mainline and has survived for this long since "no-one" knew that it was a pure device adder module, which doesn't belong in mainline.

flexfb was removed because it will never be ported to the DRM graphics subsystem due to its nature. The init= DT property is not accepted.

fbtft will now only work with Device Tree due to the above mentioned disruptive gpio rework. See the Device-Tree page.

See https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki for details.

Anyway, I'm curious if you managed to make this display work on kernel 5. I have one myself and gave up after so many headaches trying to make it work (guessing and matching pinouts, trying to instal fbtft module, and so on).
Take care!